# Count level 1 size per level 0 in multi index and add new column

Tags: python, pandas

What is a pythonic way of counting level 1 size per level 0 in multi index and creating a new column (named `counts`).  I can achieve this in the following way but would like to gain an understanding of any simpler approaches:

**Code**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'STNAME':['AL'] * 3 + ['MI'] * 4, 
                   'CTYNAME':list('abcdefg'),
                   'COL': range(7) }).set_index(['STNAME','CTYNAME'])
print(df)


               COL 
STNAME CTYNAME
AL      a      0    
        b      1    
        c      2    
MI      d      3    
        e      4    
        f      5    
        g      6    

df1 = df.groupby(level=0).size().reset_index(name='count')

counts = df.merge(df1,left_on="STNAME",right_on="STNAME")["count"].values

df["counts"] = counts
```

This is the desired output:

```
               COL counts
STNAME CTYNAME
AL      a      0    3
        b      1    3
        c      2    3
MI      d      3    4
        e      4    4
        f      5    4
        g      6    4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby.transform` with size here instead of merging:

```
output = df.assign(Counts=df.groupby(level=0)['COL'].transform('size'))
```

---

```
print(output)

                COL  Counts
STNAME CTYNAME             
AL     a          0       3
       b          1       3
       c          2       3
MI     d          3       4
       e          4       4
       f          5       4
       g          6       4
```